# Undefined index error 4

Tags: php, wordpress

in my plugin option page, i used an option checkbox.  when it checked, this is ok. but when i unchecked it, there showing an error, this :

```
Undefined index: enable in C:\xampp\htdocs\horror\wp-content\plugins\self-photo-gallery\photo-gallery.php on line 173
/>
```

the line 173 is :

```
<input id="spg_settings[enable]" name="spg_settings[enable]" type="checkbox"  value="1" <?php checked(1, $spg_options['enable']); ?> />
```

but there is another fields

```
<input type="text" id="spg_settings[twitter_url]" name="spg_settings[twitter_url]" value="<?php echo $spg_options['twitter_url']; ?>"/>
```

it works fine and didn't showing any error like this.

Comment: check again, was a mistake in the code

Comment: i think i cant make you understand.  this was worked before which you have answered now. but now i used your code, but its didn't saved anything. my previous was worked fine. 

my problem is here, 

    
    <input id="spg_settings[enable]" name="spg_settings[enable]" type="checkbox"  value="1" <?php checked(1, $spg_options['enable']); ?> />



sorry, not for putting the code in correct way

Comment: add it as <input id="spg_settings['enable']" name="spg_settings['enable']" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php checked(1, $spg_options['enable']); ?> />

Comment: Again check my updated answer. It should work

Comment: yap. thank you very much. now thats worked. but if i use quotes, its not checked, but without quotes, its checked when saved.

so, all if fine. thank you. i am using this without the quotes. is it wrong to use this without quotes ?

Comment: thank you. works fine. can you please say if you have time , why i used here zero (0)

Comment: '0' in the check function?

Comment: yes, your last update. $spg_options['enable'] : 0); here ?

Comment: I do not know your checked function. But what I have written is a ternary operator. Means if $spg_options['enable'] is set it will return $spg_options['enable']' value, if not it will return '0' as default value. You might write false instead of '0' also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add single quotes.

Use `spg_settings['enable']` instead

Always use quotes around a string literal array index. For example, $foo['bar'] is correct, while $foo[bar] is not. But why? It is common to encounter this kind of syntax in old scripts:

```
<?php
$foo[bar] = 'enemy';
echo $foo[bar];
// etc
?>
```

This is wrong, but it works. The reason is that this code has an undefined constant (bar) rather than a string ('bar' - notice the quotes). PHP may in the future define constants which, unfortunately for such code, have the same name. It works because PHP automatically converts a bare string (an unquoted string which does not correspond to any known symbol) into a string which contains the bare string. For instance, if there is no defined constant named bar, then PHP will substitute in the string 'bar' and use that.

**UPDATE1:**

replace

```
<input type="text" id="spg_settings['twitter_url']" name="spg_settings['twitter_url']" value="<?php echo $spg_options['twitter_url']; ?>"/>
```

with follow line of code

```
<input type="text" id="spg_settings['twitter_url']" name="spg_settings['twitter_url']" value="<?php echo (isset($spg_options['twitter_url'])) ? $spg_options['twitter_url'] : ''; ?>"/>
```

**UPDATE2:**

And replace

```
<input id="spg_settings['enable']" name="spg_settings['enable']" type="checkbox"  value="1" <?php checked(1, $spg_options['enable']); ?> />
```

with

```
<input id="spg_settings['enable']" name="spg_settings['enable']" type="checkbox"  value="1" <?php checked(1, (isset($spg_options['enable'])) ? $spg_options['enable'] : 0); ?> />
```

For more information check [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Post your updated code which is throwing error as an update in question

Comment: if i use with single quotes like 
id="spg_settings['enable']" name="spg_settings[enable]" , the result is same as before. 

but i put another fields of a text type : 

<input type="text" id="spg_settings[twitter_url]" name="spg_settings[twitter_url]" value="<?php echo $spg_options['twitter_url']; ?>"/>

but this works fine. i dont understant what is the problem of anoter field

Comment: @aarif, Put in the question as an UPDATE That would be more readable. Which worked which did not work

Comment: if i use quotes , result is same

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<input id="<?php echo $spg_settings['enable'];?>" name="<?php echo $spg_settings['enable'];?>" type="checkbox"  value="1" <?php checked(1, $spg_options['enable']); ?> />
```

Comment: if i use this, another error showing with the previous one, that is , the option now are not saving

Comment: it means your `$spg_settings['enable']` or `$spg_options['enable']` is not set

Answer (score 0):

Try to put quotes and perform `print` when using the array index values:

```
<input id="<?php print $spg_settings['enable'];?>" name="<?php print $spg_settings['enable'];?>" type="checkbox"  value="1" <?php checked(1, $spg_options['enable']); ?> />
```

Comment: its not working. result is same as before. i put another fields of a text type : 

<input type="text" id="spg_settings[twitter_url]" name="spg_settings[twitter_url]" value="<?php echo $spg_options['twitter_url']; ?>"/> but this works fine.